# How to Improve "having sum" query

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I have this query:

```
 Select 
     DescFornecedor, DescUsuario, Classificacao,
     Sum(Tempo) as Tempo,   
     Case Classificacao  
        When 'Agendamento' Then 2  
        When 'Aguardando cadastro' Then 3  
        When 'Descarte' Then 8  
        When 'Desistência' Then 7  
        When 'Em Pausa' Then 4  
        When 'Em Volta' Then 10  
        When 'Entrevista' Then 1  
        When 'Filtro' Then 5  
        When 'Outros' Then 9  
        When 'Recusa' Then 6  
        When 'Sem Atividade' Then 11  
    End as Ordem   
from 
   vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade t1 With(NoLock)  
Where 
   Not Exists (Select 0 
               from vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade t2 With(NoLock)  
               Where T1.CodUsuario = t2.CodUsuario    
               Group by CodUsuario  
               Having Sum(tempo) <> MAx(tempoLogado))  
Group By 
    DescFornecedor, DescUsuario, Classificacao
```

When we use it, it returns the results in 30~1min.

Now I've made some adjustments:

```
Select DescFornecedor,DescUsuario,Classificacao,Sum(t1.Tempo) as Tempo,   
   Case Classificacao  
 When 'Agendamento' Then 2  
 When 'Aguardando cadastro' Then 3  
 When 'Descarte' Then 8  
 When 'Desistência' Then 7  
 When 'Em Pausa' Then 4  
 When 'Em Volta' Then 10  
 When 'Entrevista' Then 1  
 When 'Filtro' Then 5  
 When 'Outros' Then 9  
 When 'Recusa' Then 6  
 When 'Sem Atividade' Then 11  
  End as Ordem   
  from vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade t1 With(NoLock)  
    inner join (   

select  CodUsuario, SUM(tempo) as Tempo, MAX(tempologado) as TempoLogado   
from  vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade with(nolock)      
group by CodUsuario  

 ) t2  
   on   t1.CodUsuario = t2.CodUsuario and  
  t2.Tempo = t2.TempoLogado      
  Group By DescFornecedor,DescUsuario,Classificacao
```

But i's stil slow ! lasting 10~20secs.

How can i improve this query? 
i'm out of ideas.

don't know what to do with the time comparison.

Thank you very much.

( Indexes and stats are ok, not even the trace can help me now )

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: What's the number of rows in the table, and do you have index on CodUsuario? I also guess by the naming that vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade is a view. Is it based on a single table or you have some joins in there?

Comment: In the view "vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade" i have 3,583 rows ( 4secs to show results ). the "CodUsuario" is not a column on a table in the database, we use it with the views.Can i add a index on a view's column? is this that " indexed view"?

The "vwPercentualProducao" returns only 11 Rows.

I'm using SQL 2008 r2

Comment: You should definitely create an index on CodUsuario then, that is the problem. 3,583 rows is very small, the query will perform in terms of milliseconds if the index is created!

Comment: Thanks you very much. I see here, to create a indexed view i need to use 2parts name, like dbo.view. But the view calls another view, and i need to schemabind that view too, but that view calls ANOTHER view...it's endless !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no typo in the second query, I have a problem with this part:

```
...on ... and t2.Tempo = t2.TempoLogado
```

The second criteria is based upon only t2, so can be removed from the join criteria and be handled inside t2, by adding:

```
...having SUM(tempo) = MAX(tempologado)
```

I'm not sure if it makes much improvement, though.

**UPDATE:** Since CodUsuario is a computed column in a view, the solution is to alter the view to be an indexed view and then create an index.

```
create index CodUsuario on vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade(CodUsuario)
```

Comment: I think this will help me. i'm getting this error:

Cannot create index on view 'vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade' because the view is not schema bound.

It says i need to create the view with WITH SCHEMABINDING.

i will get a talk with the coder to see if he can help me with this:

Answer (score 0):

try [cross apply](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/07/07/using-cross-apply-to-optimize-joins-on-between-conditions.aspx)

```
cross apply (   

select  CodUsuario, SUM(tempo) as Tempo, MAX(tempologado) as TempoLogado   
from  vwProducaoGeralTempoLogadoSemAtividade with(nolock)      
group by CodUsuario  

 ) t2  
   where  t1.CodUsuario = t2.CodUsuario and  
  t2.Tempo = t2.TempoLogado      
  Group By DescFornecedor,DescUsuario,Classificacao
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I created an index on  the table's view, and it worked.